# How to Get DOM Access of other chrome extensions in My chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi I want to access the DOM of other Chrome extension page in my chrome extension.

for example:-

When you Open lastpass chrome extension, the url comes like -

"chrome-extension://hdokinpimasdfkedhacegeplioahd/vault.html"

But My extension is not working on these urls even if I put `"matches":    ["<all_urls>"]`  in my manifest.json file

can anyone please help me

Comment: Perhaps by enabling chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls

Comment: @DanielHerr: I believe that you are confusing `chrome://` and `chrome-extension://` URI schemes. That flag should only allow access to `chrome://` URIs, not to `chrome-extension://` ones. I haven't tested it though.

Answer (score 2):

Content scripts can't access `chrome-extension://` pages, no matter in its own extension page or others.

Comment: Is there any other way ?

Comment: @AdityaMishra, to my knowledge, the answer would be no.